# DIY Mains Networking

Tags: networking, router, lan

I am working on a project but we have one massive problem. The project we are working on needs mains networking but we need to create our own mains networking and cant just use another company's (for obvious reasons). Would it be possible with an arduino? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: There's a good reason only 2-3 companies make powerline networking chips and there's *one* set of standards. Well, many good reasons, but fundamentally, power line networking is *hard*. You intentionally create 'noise' in power mains then filter out the noise you want on top of the other accidental noise. In some cases this may cause unwanted radio noise (which is why we don't have common broadband over powerline). If you need to ask this question, well, another option might be a better idea.

Comment: +1, unless you're an experienced electrical engineer with a big budget, you wont manage this.

Comment: If it's home automation look at arduino and X10 protocol